# Online Android Game Server

Tags: android

How to create a game server for Online Android Game? I was thinking to create a Multiplayer Scrabble Game in an Android composed of two to four players.. thanks for the replies. it can help to my thesis. thanks.

Comment: What are the requirements for your server? What did you try to do? Imagine if somebody asked you: "How to make a cake?". Would you know how to answer? No? Is your question any better? Hint: read the FAQ.

Comment: As already stated, you should be more specific on your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a couple of options:

- Webservices-> Rest services (for non realtime games like scrabble and
  keeping highscores etc)
- Tcp Sockets (for reatime games)

Both can be programmed in languages like C# and java, webservices also in php